# Как запустить PHP несколько раз без Cron

Tags: php, cron, планировщик-задач

Столкнулся с такой задачей, что нужно запустить PHP скрипт несколько раз, но не через Cron, т.к. там периодичность - минимум минута, а это очень много.

Итого:

Мне необходимо, чтобы мой скрипт работал, как будто выводит информацию в echo, но это не так. Т.е. Его действия конечны и при каждом новом проходе он работает с новыми значениями переменных.

Я читал о всяческих способах запуска PHP в фоне или использованию AJAX, но это все как-то не прижилось.

Спасибо заранее за Напутствие, если я понятно описал задачу!

Comment: Задачу вообще не понятно описали (извините). Можно запускать скрипт через cron. Проверять, не работает ли он еще с прошлого запуска с помощью `flock(файл скрипта)`. Если работает, то выход, иначе выполнять цикл: задача + `sleep(нужная задержка)`.

Comment: Какая стоит исходная задача?

Comment: На Хабре есть [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/132609/) про вашу задачу.

Comment: Предположу что вам нужен WebSocket